# Visualize progress on GoogleMaps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm creating a small test application to visualise my progress on a Google Map using the Google Maps Android API. (API: [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/))

My backend serves me data about the polylines between two given coordinates. The Android application decodes the data and draw the polylines on the GoogleMaps view.

[image]

I'd like to visualise the route that i've already done. (So grey out the parts/polylines i've already driven on.
I've already tried coloring the polylines i've passed by calculating the closest distance to a polyline with a given treshold. But I seem to be unable to color a polyline with:

- setColor() - polyline
- color() - polylineoptions

There seems no way to update an already existing polyline. If i remove all markers, polylines, .. and redraw the polylines with the updated values on every location change, it is really laggy.

I was wondering if there are some better/alternative ways to visualise my progress on a map.

```
private void drawPolyline() {
    if (polyLines == null) polyLines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
    if (mRouteInformation == null) return;

    Log.i("NavigationActivity", "Drawing polyline");

    for (int i = 0; i < mRouteInformation.getRouteGuidance().size(); i++) {
        RoutePart part = mRouteInformation.getRouteGuidance().get(i);

        if (part != null && part.getRouteVisualization() != null) {
            List<PolylineOptions> options = MapsUtils.decodePolyLines(mRouteInformation.getRouteGuidance().get(i).getRouteVisualization());
            if (options != null && options.size() > 0 && mGoogleMap != null) {

                //Add the polylines to Maps.
                for (PolylineOptions polylineOptions : options) {
                    if (!isFinishing()) {
                        polyLines.add(mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you "recolor" polylines? I'm sure it works because i've code in my apps that enable users to change the color of the polylines

Comment: I tried using setColor on the Polyline and color on the PolylineOptions. But none seem to work. What did you use? Do you need to reinvalidate the map or something?

Comment: nope. 
color on polylineOptions works only Before drawing the polyline, setColor on polyline instead works on an object already added to the map and kept as variable (you did not put that code, so I can't understand if you do it correctly).

In my code I just take the polyline I want to recolor and do:
myPolyline.setColor(Color.RED) or similar

Comment: I've updated my code above: drawPolyline(). This code is called in onResume and draws the polyline on the map. A route guidance is received from the server which contains routeparts. These routeparts exists out of polylineoptions which are decoded with MapUtils.

Comment: ok so here
1- If you call it in onResume, you should clear the map before adding new polylines, because it can be already plines before the onPause.
2-You have to set the color of polyline options in decodePolyLines method.
3- What is isFinishing() ? is it true?

Comment: If onPause is called, does it remove or clear the map itself? After opening the application, pausing it (onpause) and the onresume, the map is cleared. Does something happen internally when pausing?

Comment: Usually not, it depends on how you develop the app. If the fragment is retained not all the shapes are removed. To be sure that this is done, call a map.clear() before adding all your data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81541/discussion-between-xverhelstx-and-n-dorigatti).